# External Terminal / Debug outside the IDE

Tags: c#, xamarin, ide, visual-studio-mac, monodevelop

I'm starting to use Xamarin Studio, and migrating from VS to it, but when I try to run a console application (the unique one loaded at the moment), fails and throws an exception in Console.Clear() (Supposing I can't do that in an integrated debugger), then i thought that one way to solve it was by compiling it and running it, like Visual Studio does, and Debug the application outside the IDE, but I can't figure out how. Could someone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

**EDIT:** For any reason, it runs in the embedded window when selecting Release, but it can't read input, so it gets stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the project option to have it run your console app in an external console:

#### Visual Studio For Mac:

`Project Options` / `Run` / `Configurations` / `Default` / `Run on external console`

#### Xamarin Studio:

Project Options / Run / General / Run on external console
[image]

[image]

Comment: Should this setting launch a Terminal instance, which loads `pwsh`?  Does your solution need a separate console-app project?

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by running your program in a separate console window.  It’s easy to do, although you need to follow the steps closely.

The first step is to bring up the project’s options window.  You do this by finding your ‘Solution’ panel (normally on the left side of the Visual Studio window), and within that panel you much right-click on the project (this is pointed to by the “1” arrow in the below picture).  Once that context menu appears you need to click on “Options”, which may be very close to the bottom)

[image: Right-clicking on project]

Once the Project Options window appears, you should click on Run  Configurations  Default (next to the ‘1’ arrow, below), and then check off Run On External Console (next to the ‘2’ arrow, below)

[image: Project Options dialog]

Once that’s done you’ll need to click the ‘Ok’ button.

Everything should work fine at this point, but it’s always good to double-check: try running a program that asks you to type something and verify that it’s working correctly.

Comment: QUestion: given that there's already an accepted answer is it ok (etiquette-wise) to offer up another one?
(I typed it up for something else and figured that I might leave it here, too)

Comment: I don't have a Mac myself - can anyone tell me how to "right-click" on Mac? :)

Comment: It's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click.