# Unable to run the console application as tools goes missing in Visual Studio 2019 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was running my console programs on mac without any problems and getting output in the console window a few days back. Now my unity window was open when I opened Visual Studio for running a console application (which I took from recent projects) and my tools to run or debug was gone. I clicked run from the menu but nothing is happening. I clicked run - start debugging I am getting an error like this

> A ӳcriptӠcan״ go after this identifier.

I updated my mac to latest version - mac OS Catalina 10.15.2 - recently.

[image: Tools missing]

The above image is what has happened.

A few days back my tool set view was similar to the image shown below.How to see the tools again.

I also tried this option - [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056993/1351156) options was checked.

[image: What I am looking for]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External Terminal / Debug outside the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709898/external-terminal-debug-outside-the-ide)

Comment: those options are checked ..no issues with that