# How to run a console application in an external terminal in visual studio for mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I need to be able to run a console application in an external terminal in visual studio for mac, and I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709898/external-terminal-debug-outside-the-ide) and visual studio shows this:

[image: image without option to run in external console]

instead of this:

[image: image with option to run in external console]

Is there any way I can run it in a external console while still using visual studio for mac?

This is the About Visual Studio window:

[image: about visual studio]

Comment: Uncheck "Run in Terminal Window" and see what happens.

Comment: To run your console app in Terminal.app instead of the integrated terminal you can open Preferences - Other - Terminal and then uncheck 'Enable integrated terminal'.